# Grunt - Task "undefined" not found

Tags: gruntjs

I'm currently getting the same error for all tasks that I run via grunt.

```
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose
Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build,default,nick,server,test

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task
Warning: Task "undefined" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

The last warning happens for any task I run.

Grunfile.js(important stuff):

```
...
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/libs/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    ...
});
...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTask('nick', [ ]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint'
]);
```

running jshint by itself works fine..

```
grunt jshint 
>Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 52 files lint free.
>>
>>Done, without errors.
```

Done, without errors.

Any help?  Let me know if there is any other info you need to help.

Nick.

Comment: Try removing the empty "nick" task registration

Comment: @nschonni I added that to test it, it didn't cause any issues  Updating `grunt-cli` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and all I needed to do was update grunt with:

```
npm --global update grunt-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential cause of this problem is having double commas in a `Gruntfile.js`'s `registerTask` section. For instance:

`grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean',, 'uglify:dist']);`

Note that this will also produce the same error:

`grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean', /*unnecessarytask */, 'uglify:dist']);`